# How do you manage conflicts when items in dependencies have the same name?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-management

This is both a question about Angular architecture and how to work with it.

I created a really simple Angular App. It has a main module called `App`, and `App` has two dependencies, `Dep1`, `Dep2`. Both of the `Dep`s, have a constant called `theConst`. So when `theConst` is used in the `App`, **how does Angular decide what to use?**

As it stands now, when I test the app, Angular chooses `Dep2`'s value, which is injected second. What if I want to refer to `Dep1`'s value in some places and `Dep2`'s in others?

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Dependency1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Dependency2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <h1>{{greet}}</h1>
        <h5>{{const}}</h5>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('Dep1', [])
.constant('theConst', "Number One!");

angular.module('Dep2', [])
.constant('theConst', "Number Two!");


angular.module('App', ['Dep1', 'Dep2'])
.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', 'theConst', function($scope, theConst){
    $scope.greet = "Howdie!";

    $scope.const = theConst;
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular modules are a strange thing (I don't like them - but that's a personal opinion). They only provide an abstract grouping, no namespacing, no bundling/script loading.

In the end it comes to this: **you have to make sure no 2 artifacts have the same name by yourself**. There may be plugins for Grunt/Gulp/you build system that help you, but I do not know any.

Angular will **choose the last artifact with a given name it encounters**. (This can get funny when artifacts are declared in multiple files.)

Comment: That's why the documentation advices to namespace your dependencies by yourself (namely, `Dep1.theConst` and `Dep2.theConst`).

Comment: Thanks Nikos for the answer and @Blackhole for the useful comment which is more what I was looking for.